# Unbind Ctrl+v in Enhanced Editor

Tags: sas

I don't want paste to be bound to `Ctrl+v` in the Enhanced Editor.

I have gone into `Tools > Options > Enhanced Editor Keys`, selected `paste from clipboard` and removed the default bindings of `Ctrl+v` and `Shift+Insert`.  However, both `Ctrl+v` and `Shift+Insert` continue to paste from the clipboard.

I know that not all bindings are managed through the interface described above.  For instance, there is separate binding management within the `DMKEYS` and `VMKEYS` screens.

Is there another location, perhaps in the registry, which I can edit and remove the default `paste from clipboard` bindings?  If so, how do I do it?

Comment: I would be very surprised if this were possible, unfortunately.